# Show $T:V → W$ is injective

Tags: linear-algebra

I am defining a unique linear map as $T: V → W$, by $Tv_i = w_i $ for $i = 1,...,n$.
Such that $n = dim V  \leq dim W = m$.
Then trying to show this is injective function.
so I was trying to say $T(v_1,..,v_n) = c_1 w_1 + ...+ c_2 w_n $ for some constants in the field. Then$ c_1 w_1 + ...+ c_2 w_n = 0$ if and only if (v_1,..,v_n ) = (0,...,0) . And since $w_1,...,w_n$ are a basis they are linearly independent so we have null$T = {\{(0,...,0)}\}$ , so $T$ is injective.
Can someone please verify this? I want to show $T: V→ W$ is injective.
 Thank you !

Comment: Yes, the null space is $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but there some few minor mistakes. I think you assumed that $v_1,...,v_n$ is a basis of $V$, then you have for all $v=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i\in{V}$:

$Tv=T(\sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i Tv_i=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i w_i$.

Suppose $0=Tv=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i w_i$.

But $w_1,...,w_n$ are linearly independant because they are a subset of your chosen basis $w_1,...,w_m$ of $W$. Therefore $c_1=...=c_n=0$ and you can finally conclude $v=0$.

Hence $kerT=\{0\}$, which means $T$ is injective.